# What's the HTML5 3D canvas? How is it different with WebGL?

Tags: html5, 3d

I heard about *3D canvas*. It's strange for me. Because I know there's already a industrial standard 3D API *WebGL*. What's that? How is it different with WebGL?

Comment: 3D canvas is WebGL. https://wiki.mozilla.org/Canvas:3D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WebGL is rendered onto a `canvas` element with a context acquired from it. So "3D canvas" and WebGL are pretty much synonyms.